# Using options_from_collection_for select with a model that has a belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting the error:

> NoMethodError in Providers#add_location Showing
>   /vagrant/ipanmv2/app/views/providers/add_location.html.erb where line
>
> ## 13 raised:
>
> undefined method `dba' for # Extracted
>   source (around line #13): 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
>
> ```
> <tr>
>   <td>          
>     <% if @provider.provider_locations.count >0 %>
>        <%= select_tag "provider_locations",  options_from_collection_for_select(@provider.provider_locations, :id , @provider.provider_locations.map{ |j| j.dba }), :multiple => true %>
>     <% else %>
>        <%= select_tag "provider_locations", "<option></option>".html_safe, :multiple => true, :style => "width: 300px" %>       
>     <% end %>
> ```
>
> Rails.root: /vagrant/ipanmv2
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/views/providers/add_location.html.erb:13:in `block in
>   _app_views_providers_add_location_html_erb__446308859_95329970' app/views/providers/add_location.html.erb:13:in`
>   _app_views_providers_add_location_html_erb__446308859_95329970'
>   Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"id"=>"4332"} Toggle session dump Toggle env dump Response
>
> Headers:
>
> None

I am trying to get at data in this options_from_collection_for_select but through a model that belongs to another.

Provider has a provider_location which belongs to group_location which in turn has a group_id, an address_id and a name: dba   I want to use that name in the list:

With the code:

```
<tr>
        <td>          
          <% if @provider.provider_locations.count >0 %>
            <%= select_tag "provider_locations", options_from_collection_for_select(@provider.provider_locations, :id , @provider.provider_locations.map{ |j| j.dba }), :multiple => true %>
          <% else %>
            <%= select_tag "provider_locations", "<option></option>".html_safe, :multiple => true, :style => "width: 300px" %>       
          <% end %>                   
        </td>
      </tr>
```

I know from another stack overflow question I have that my map is what is breaking this, though the fix from the other question won't help here since i have to somehow essentially for all locations on that provider get every group location and dig into that to get the group locations name.  Not sure how to approach this or what my types are.

I know I somehow have to map all the group location name (as field dba in model group_location) to the provider locations group_location_id somehow.  Just no idea how to do this.

Comment: Assuming your first provider has locations (if not, grab one that does), what do you get if you go to the console and do this:
`@provider = Provider.first`
then do this
`@provider.provider_locations`
and then do this
`@provider.provider_locations.map{ |j| j.dba }`

Comment: gives me an undefined method 'dba' error.

Comment: I can say j.group_location.dba and it finds the name, but then I get the error that it is neither a symbol nor a string.  That is to say it works fine in the rails console returning ["my group location name"]  but it fails in the actual html.erb file.

Comment: Why is your name inside an array? in any case, if you use `.first` at the end like so: 
`@provider.provider_locations.map{ |j| j.dba.first }` it will probably work.

Comment: it is how the relationships work.  Inside a provider location has a group location and that is where the DBA name is. Oh i see what you are saying though it was coming back as a  name but it is in an array.   so j.group_location.dba.first is what I want.

Comment: Well maybe I was mistaken.  The provider location has a provider and a group_location and in that it has the dba.  The provider_location can have many group locations for a given provider.  Then I want to map all those group locations by name in my little select tag

Comment: I figured it out i was using the map wrong:      `<%= select_tag "provider_locations", options_from_collection_for_select(@provider.provider_locations.map{|j| j.group_location}, :id , :dba), :multiple => true %>`

Comment: ahh glad you got it working!